# Arrange items in a legend in a defined way

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
DF = data.frame(val = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), param = rep(letters[1:5],2), x = rep(c('X', 'Y'), 5))
ggplot(data = DF) + geom_bar(aes(y = val, fill = param, x = x), stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge2(preserve = 'single')) + guides(fill = guide_legend(nrom = 2, byrow = TRUE))
```

While I can generate the plot, however, I want to arrange the items in the legend in a specific way as below.

1. First 2 items i.e. `a & b` should be in the first row
2. Remaining items should be arranged in an array fashion **with 3 columns and applicable number of rows** based on the number of items except first 2 i.e. `a & b`, starting from the second row (first row will only contain `a & b`)
3. I also want to **bold-face** the items `a & b` only, in the legend

Is there any way to achieve such custom arrangement?

Based on the kind answer from @stefan, I modified my code as below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

DF = data.frame(val = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), param = rep(letters[1:5],2), x = rep(c('X', 'Y'), 5))

DF$param <- factor(DF$param, c("a", "b", "spacer", "c", "d", "e"))

pal_fill <- scales::hue_pal()(5)
names(pal_fill) <- letters[1:5]

pal_fill <- c(pal_fill, spacer = "transparent")

ggplot(data = DF) +
  geom_col(aes(y = val, fill = param, x = x), alpha = 0.6,
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = pal_fill,
    drop = FALSE,
    labels = ~ dplyr::case_match(
      .x, "spacer" ~ "", c("a", "b") ~ paste0("**", .x, "**"),
      .default = .x)
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
    nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE
  )) +
  theme(
    legend.position=c(.9,.75),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = alpha('#e5e5e5', 0.60)),
    #legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(),
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )
```

As you see, I see a `white` patch in the legend. This actually goes off if I remove `alpha = 0.6` in `geom_col`. This is strange to me as I failed to understand the connection between `alpha` in `geom_col` and legend items.

Is there any way to correct this i.e. remove the `white` patch?

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then one approach to achieve your desired result would be to add some fake legend entries for which we make the legend keys "invisible" by removing the labels and setting the fill color to e.g. `"transparent"`.

As a first step this requires to convert `param` to a factor and adding the fake elements at the correct position. Additionally we have to set `drop=FALSE` for the fill scale so that the unused fake elements are actually displayed in the legend. Finally, bolding only some of the legend elements is the easiest task and could be achieved via `ggtext::element_markdown`.

Note: Depending on the `theme` setting the fill color to `"transparent"` is not sufficient to make the fake elements invisible, e.g. in case of the default `theme_grey` the keys have a grey background fill. Hence, I added `legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent")` to make the background fill transparent as well.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

DF$param <- factor(DF$param, c("a", "b", "spacer", "c", "d", "e"))

pal_fill <- scales::hue_pal()(5)
names(pal_fill) <- letters[1:5]

pal_fill <- c(pal_fill, spacer = "transparent")

ggplot(data = DF) +
  geom_col(aes(y = val, fill = param, x = x),
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = pal_fill,
    drop = FALSE,
    labels = ~ dplyr::case_match(
      .x, "spacer" ~ "", c("a", "b") ~ paste0("**", .x, "**"),
      .default = .x)
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
    nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE
  )) +
  theme(
    legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(),
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** Have to admit that I don't know exactly what's the issue but a fix would be to set `alpha` for the "spacer" to zero for which I use `after_scale` and an `if_else` in `geom_col`:

```
ggplot(data = DF) +
  geom_col(
    aes(
      y = val, fill = param, x = x,
      alpha = after_scale(if_else(fill != "transparent", .6, 0))
    ),
    position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = pal_fill,
    drop = FALSE,
    labels = ~ dplyr::case_match(
      .x, "spacer" ~ "", c("a", "b") ~ paste0("**", .x, "**"),
      .default = .x
    )
  ) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(
    nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE
  )) +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(.9, .75),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = alpha("#e5e5e5", 0.60)),
    #legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(),
    legend.key = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for saving my day. I am sure I would have tried all day long. Interestingly it was not possibly to find a way to access the individual legend elements in ggplot. I tried a little with `library(cowplot)
legend <- get_legend(p)
legend_items <- legend$grobs[[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$children
for (i in seq_along(legend_items)) {
  print(legend_items[[i]])
}` but no success. And now that we have a solution I stop to search!

Comment: @TarJae Also have thought about this and for more general customizations it is the way to go. Unfortunately I do that only occasionally and know that it will cost me a lot of time and effort. That's why I always try to figure out a quick and dirty ggplot2 hack as a first step. (:

Comment: @stefan I am wondering if it possible to provide some invisible colour for `spacer ` instead of `white`. In my `ggplot` the background of plot area and legend is different from white, so current `white` colour is visible. I tried with `colorspace:: lighten('#ffffff', 0)` - but still the color for `spacer `  is visible

Comment: Sure. The reason I used `"white"` was that the legend key in the default theme has a grey background fill. I just made an edit where I use a `transparent` fill for both the "spacer" and the background fill of the legend key. Not sure whether this is sufficient to fix the the issue for your theme.

Comment: @stefan Thanks for this awesome code. However what I observed is that if I add `alpha` in `geom_col`, the `white` patch in legend appears. I have updated my original post with this finding. Is it a bug?

Comment: Don't think that this is a bug. But IMHO legends are tricky as we have a legend.background, a legend.box.background, a legend.key, ... (:. See my edit for a possible fix.